# How to read text file line by line?

Tags: android, arraylist

My Goal is to be able to save as many high scores from my application to my text file i create using FileOutputStream. I then want to be able to read from the file and put each line into an array list item. While using InputStreamReader I am able to load all of the lines of text from the text file into the variable s. My problem now is i want to take each line from the text file and save it into an array list item. How would i accomplish this?

```
   Example string variables for high scores:
   String myStr = "Ryan 150 hard \n";
   String myStr2 = "Andrew 200 Medium \n";
   public void saveClick(){

    try{

        //String myNum = Integer.toString(life);

        FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("storetext.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        OutputStreamWriter outputWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);

        outputWriter.write(myStr);
        outputWriter.write(myStr2);
        outputWriter.close();
        /*OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput(STORETEXT, 0));

        out.write(life);

        out.close();*/

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Save Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    catch(Throwable t){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Save Unsuccessful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}

public void readFileInEditor(){

    try{

        FileInputStream fileIn = openFileInput("storetext.txt");

        InputStreamReader InputRead = new InputStreamReader(fileIn);

        char [] inputBuffer = new char[READ_BLOCK_SIZE];
        String s = "";
        int charRead;


        while ((charRead=InputRead.read(inputBuffer))>0){

            //char to string conversion
            String readString = String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer,0,charRead);

            s += readString;

        }

        InputRead.close();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Text: " + s , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //myText.setText("" + s);

        try{

            //life = Integer.parseInt(s);

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "My Num: " + life , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
        catch(NumberFormatException e){

            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not get number" + life , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

    }
    catch(java.io.FileNotFoundException e){

        //have not created it yet

    }

    catch(Throwable t){

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Exception: "+t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your life easier, better to use (1) `BufferedReader::readline()` method, or (2) `Scanner::nextLine()` method. And add each line to a `List<String>` in the for loop.

A simple example:

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
String curLine = null;

BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("storetext.txt"));
while ((curLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
  lines.add(curLine);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. If i wanted to use the BufferedReader method how would it look for the for loop, i am just very new to java?

Comment: @RyanWing I've added some sample code to the answer

Comment: I have implemented the code you have given as well as added from what i had. I kept the FileInputStream and DataInputStream when including your code and am just using 2 String variables as a test. When i Toast out the result i am getting the second line form the text file twice instead of the first line of the text file then the second line of the text file. Any ideas on why that would be happening?

Comment: @RyanWing Then how do you read the lines? DataInputStream:readline() has been deprecated.

Comment: @RyanWing Could you please try BufferedReader instead of DataInputStream and see if it works? If still not, please share the modified code so I can take a look.

Comment: As you just wrote that I got rid of the DataInputStream and my code started to work. I will look more into both methods so I have a better understanding! Thanks for the suggestions and help.

Comment: @RyanWing Glad it helped. Could you please mark it as the correct answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [BufferedReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html?is-external=true) to read line by line and put them in an ArrayList right away.